# How to return an error HTML (Input Validation)

Tags: java, html, jsp, web

I am currently developing a web site (Part of a university assignment)

I just put some input validation, although when I redirect due to an error from validation,

For example:

```
 var x = document.getElementById("age").checked; 
     var y = document.getElementById("agreement").checked;
     var z = document.getElementById("sex").value;

     if(x != true & y != true & z == null)
         {
         response.sendRedirect("Register.jsp");
         }
```

I was looking to have some sort of error message appear above the form, to tell the user that they have created an error within the form. (For example, if they did not enter their Gender or did not agree to either of the checkboxes). Also noted, I will change the validation code slightly to be more specific to the error in which the person has made.

Form:

```
<h3>Register as user</h3>
        <form method="POST"  action="Register">
            <ul>
                <li>First Name: <input type="text" name ="firstName"></li>
                <li>Last Name: <input type = "text" name = "lastName"></li>
                <li>Email Address: <input type = "email" name = "email"></li>
                <li>Gender: Male <input type ="radio" name ="sex" value="male">
                    Female <input type ="radio" name ="sex" value="female"></li>
                <li>User Name <input type="text" name="username"></li>
                <li>Password <input type="password" name="password"></li>

                <li>You must be 12 or over to register to this web site. Please check if you are over 12: <input type = "checkbox" name="age"></li>
                <li>Please check this box to agree to the Terms and Conditions <input type ="checkbox" name="agreement"></li>
            </ul>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Register"> 
        </form>
```

Thank you for any help or advice you can give me, I really appreciate it as I am rather new to web development and I want to improve and understand techniques that web developers use.

Comment: First of all, I wouldn't check the input on client side

Comment: I only check inputs for the 2 check boxes and the radio button client side. I assume you mean I'd put that and the rest of the input validation server side? 

Would I be correct in saying that putting input validation on the client side would be a security problem? 

Thank you for your input

Comment: Exactly. The user is able to edit or even to completely disable Javascript. Your validation would fail here. You could do it on both sides, but that would be redundant code

Comment: Ah interesting. I'll definitely look at server side validation then. I don't suppose you can recommend a good resource for that particular topic?

Comment: @Naiyon use `php` for a backup server side validation, but to for the displaying the error messages I would say just keep the `JavaScript`, or even use `jQuery`. a hint would be to put the error message in a predefined div on client side validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var validate = function(form) {
  var errors = [];
  if (!form.sex[0].checked && !form.sex[1].checked) {
    errors.push('Please select a gender');
  }
  if (!form.agreement.checked) {
    errors.push('Please agree to T&C');
  }
  if (errors.length) {
    alert(errors.join('\n'));
    return false;
  }
  return true;
};
```

```html
<h3>Register as user</h3>
<form method="POST" action="Register.jsp" onsubmit="return validate(this);">
  <ul>
    <li>First Name:
      <input type="text" name="firstName">
    </li>
    <li>Last Name:
      <input type="text" name="lastName">
    </li>
    <li>Email Address:
      <input type="email" name="email">
    </li>
    <li>Gender: Male
      <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Female
      <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">
    </li>
    <li>User Name
      <input type="text" name="username">
    </li>
    <li>Password
      <input type="password" name="password">
    </li>

    <li>You must be 12 or over to register to this web site. Please check if you are over 12:
      <input type="checkbox" name="age">
    </li>
    <li>Please check this box to agree to the Terms and Conditions
      <input type="checkbox" name="agreement">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. It's perfect for what I'm doing for now! I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this. I have an html element which is hidden by default.
It is red and take the whole width of the div I put into.

And I've a function to manage errors :

```
var manageError = function(message) {
    $("#element").val(message); // or     $("#element").html(message) I guess
    $("#element").clearQueue();
    $("#element")slideDown(200).delay(10000).slideUp(200);
};
```

Does it help ?

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery to do this. since you are learning..it will be more helpful for you.

first thing I noticed there, you have used response.sendRedirect(...); in side your javascript which is a wrong approach.
And in your form, don't use un-ordered list like approach, simply use div tags.

I will give a simple example:

```html
<h3>Register as user</h3>
<form method="POST" action="Register.jsp" id="formId">

  First Name:
  <input type="text" name="firstName">Last Name:
  <input type="text" name="lastName">

  <div id="errMsg"></div>

  <input type="button" value="submit" id="submtBtn">
</form>
```

and in your javascript file, use it with jQuery:

```js
< !DOCTYPE html >
  < html >
  < head >
  < script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" > < /script>
</head >

  < script >

  $("submtBtn").click(function({
      var errorMsg = "";
      if ($("firstName").val === '' || $("lastName").val === '') {
        errorMsg = "<b>firstName and LastName can not be empty!<b>";
        $("errMsg").html(errMsg);
        return;
      }

      $("#formId").submit();


    });


    < /script>
```

you can follow above approach.... if you're using Servlets, you could follow jQuery Ajax to submit your values. try and see...hope it will give you an idea..!

Comment: Oh, handy! Yeah, part of the assignment is to learn and understand servlets. I'm finding it a little challenging since I'm very new to web dev. JQuery Ajax eh? I'll have a look! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First put the validation code in a function and call that function.

```
function validate(){

 ..........write your validation code

}
```

Call this from submit button via `onclick` or `onchange` or `onblur` attribute of input tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use HTML 5. With the required action. They can never leave anything blank if this is in. Be aware that it might work with a space in it or something.

Try this:

```
<li>First Name: <input type="text" name ="firstName" required></li>
```